# Tornado long connection

Tags: python, tornado

Can I realize "long connection(persistent connection, not long poll)" use tornado.web.RequestHandler? Because I need contain the connection, I need receive "heart message" which send by client, So, if tornado.web.RequestHandler can do it, How can I do? And have some demo like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

RequestHandler isn't right for this, use [WebSocketHandler](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/branch2.1/websocket.html) instead. Here's an example app that receives a heartbeat from each client every second:

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import tornado.websocket


class HeartBeatReceiver(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def open(self):
        pass

    def on_message(self, message):
        print message

    def on_close(self):
        pass


class Main(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        # This could be a template, too.
        self.write('''
<script>
function sendHeartBeat() {
    ws.send("heartbeat");
    setTimeout(sendHeartBeat, 1000);
}

ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8888/websocket");
ws.onopen = sendHeartBeat;
</script>''')


application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", Main),
    (r"/websocket", HeartBeatReceiver),
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```